# Making SQL query from C++

Tags: c++, sql, visual-studio-2008, ms-access

I have connected to an MS Access database from my project.  Now I want to make a query, for example to take out data from third and fourth column.

How can I write SQL query in C++/CPP, using visual studio 2008?

Comment: You don't write queries in C++, you write them in SQL. Look up ADO.NET and similar frameworks to communicate with the database backend. It's fairly simple once you have the basics down, and it should be trivial to adapt a MS SQL Server example to communicate with Access instead.

Comment: You probably will need send the query as a string to the database server - you will need to learn how to write SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a framework like MFC, Qt, or wxWidgets, you probably want to use the database connection classes they already include.

If you're not using one of those, you probably want to look into another library specifically for the purpose, such as [DTL](http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/) or [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/).

You can obviously write your own code to talk to the database via something like OLE DB or ODBC, but they both involve quite a lot of boiler-plate, so a library helps out a *lot*.